# "Administer Taxonomy" is needed to make a user select a term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users, security

I need a user to select a term from a given vocabulary but the field is only available to a normal user if I enable "Administer Taxonomy" for them. Is there a way around this? Shouldn't I be using taxonomy for this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give an user the permission to `Administer Taxonomy` in order to **use** a vocabulary. Assuming you are using Drupal 7, as the name implies `Administer vocabularies and terms` it's a permission that allows one to **edit** and/or **delete* a term from any vocabularies. It can also be specified per vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

You can install "Vocabulary Permissions Per Role":

> You have set up some vocabularies (with some terms) like Color (Red, Green, Blue) and Shape (Toroid, Cube, Sphere). Maybe you even have a vocabulary that controls who can view a specific node (with terms) like Access control (Editors, Colleagues, World). Here comes trouble: your precious editors want to add more Colors, or reorder the terms of the Shape vocabulary (probably they want to see Sphere before Cube, who knows,) and you do NOT want to grant your editors the administer taxonomy permission, as it grants too much power (and that implies too much sharing of responsibility). Without this permission they were NOT able to do the mentioned tricks: adding terms to a vocabulary but not to another, reordering/editing terms of a vocabulary but not another's, etc.

https://drupal.org/project/vppr